# Build Tool for a React SPA

Tags: react

***The task I want to accomplish, requirements for that task:***

I'm currently in the process of selecting a build tool for a new React SPA project (without SSR or [server components](https://react.dev/blog/2023/03/22/react-labs-what-we-have-been-working-on-march-2023#react-server-components)).
The requirements are:

- the tool should be SPA focused, not full-stack, or SSR
- the tool should seamlessly (officially) support popular component libraries like MUI, should not be via some snippets someone posted
- (optional) the tool should have out of the box (or officially provided) integration with linting tools, formatting tools, TypeScript, React Testing Library, i.e. developers' experience and quality tools.

***What I already know:***

[The official React documentation](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project) suggests frameworks like Next.js, Remix, and Gatsby, but doesn't focus much on build tools for a pure React SPA, without SSR (like it was for [CRA](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app)).

What about Vite, Webpack or Parcel?
If they are [barely mentioned](https://react.dev/learn/start-a-new-react-project#can-i-use-react-without-a-framework) in the official React docs, does it mean they are not "preferred" (future-proof) options?